# Button stays selected after UIScrollView swipe event

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to fix the problem I ran into while implementing the `UIScrollView`. When button is being pressed and scrolled simultaneously, the button becomes "stuck" (It pretty much remains in the selected state and can't be interacted with anymore.

**Problem:** http://makeagif.com/Zjtj5p

What I tried so far:

- Disabling and Reenabling the `UIScrollView` inside `@IBAction` function, like `self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = false` , so the user could not scroll, when button is being tapped (I guess it's a wrong approach , since the Buttons are connected to "Touch Up Inside" event and at this stage it's too early for them to react to `self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = false`
- Disabling Buttons when the swipe gesture is recognized. I used `scrollViewDidScroll` method, however that way buttons can't be pressed at all.

I believe I need to create a method for "Touch Drag Exit" of UIButtons, and disable the `UIScrollView` when the "Touch Drag Exit" is recognized. Would that be the best approach?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?